# Yii framework unit Testing. How to mock time() and other standart functions?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, yii

I'm writing unit test for my models. Most of them use many standart functions, like time(), date() and so on. What is best approach to mock these functions in Yii testing style?

I found PHPUnit extension [Mockfunction](https://github.com/tcz/phpunit-mockfunction), but i think, that there is more elegant way to mock functions in Yii.

Help pls. Some examples will be very pleasant.

Comment: have you looked at [CTestCase](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTestCase) and related classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I "Mock" time in PHPUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371854/can-i-mock-time-in-phpunit)

Comment: You have to wrap these functions to mock their results. It might help if you post some code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but it's interesting nevertheless.

In short, if you have a library function like `time()` in your code, then obviously you cannot mock it as is. You should have some sort of completely dumb abstraction around this call like `TimeSource->now()` and your SUT should use this abscraction instead of direct call to library function. This way in your unit tests you can substitute real `TimeSource` with the fake created in any way you will find suitable, via Mockery, via PHPUnit mocks, writing fake class by hand, you name it. This fake should return controllable results for function in question, of course.