# Create test for object performing exec()

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test a php function calling `exec()`, what is the best way to do that? I use it to get the result of `git describe`:

```
class Version
{
    public function getVersionString()
    {
        $result = exec('git describe --always');

        if (false !== strpos($result, 'fatal')) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Git describe returns error: %s',
                $result
            ));
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

So I want to test if the command is executed and when an error occurs, the exception is thrown (i.e. the "expected" behaviour and the "exceptional" behaviour).

```
class VersionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testVersionResultsString()
    {
        $version = new Version();
        $result  = $version->getVersionString();

        $this->assertEquals('...', $result);
    }

    public function testVersionResultHasFatalErrorThrowsException()
    {
        // trigger something that will cause the fatal
        $this->setExpectedException('RuntimeException');

        $version = new Version();
        $result  = $version->getVersionString();
    }
}
```

Of course the class and test are for real a bit more complicated, but the essence is to capture the `exec()` somewhere. Any idea how?

Answer (score 2):

If you use namespaces, there is a trick to *mock* built-in functions, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337635/664108

So, basically you can replace `exec` with your own function, whose return values will be specified by your tests.