# Do we need to add any php library to use override_function () in php?

Tags: php

I tried below code in my computer which is giving  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function rename_function()` How to solve this?

```
<?php

rename_function('strlen', 'new_strlen');

override_function('strlen', '$string', 'return override_strlen($string);');


function override_strlen($string)
{
        return new_strlen($string); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us the reason why you want to override `strlen()`?

Comment: @RoyalBg: There are many valid cases in which you may want to override a global function. Most notably: stubbing in (unit)tests.

Comment: @berkes I don't see when you would want to override a built-in function in testing? Can you explain, thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371854/can-i-mock-time-in-phpunit/5337635#5337635

Comment: who cares why he wants to do it. that shouldn't matter. Either you can answer the question or not.

Answer (score 0):

You do need the PECL apd package for this function. Perhaps your PECL apd package is older than the required 0.2 version or not installed.

However I would strongly suggest not to rename functions. It will create confusion for other programmers who need to read the code.