# How to fake a resourse for a unit test in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, fsockopen

I had a method, that opened a socket connection, used, and then closed it. In order to make it testable, I moved the dealing with the connection to separate methods (see the code below).

Now I want to write a unit test for the `barIntrefaceMethod()` and need to mock the method `openConnection()`. With other words, I need a fake `resource`.

**Is it possible / How to "manually" create a variable of the type `resource` in PHP (in order to fake handles like "[opened files, database connections, image canvas areas and the like](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.casting)" etc.)?**

---

**`FooClass`**

```
class FooClass
{
    public function barIntrefaceMethod()
    {
        $connection = $this->openConnection();
        fwrite($connection, 'some data');
        $response = '';
        while (!feof($connection)) {
            $response .= fgets($connection, 128);
        }
        return $response;
        $this->closeConnection($connection);
    }

    protected function openConnection()
    {
        $errno = 0;
        $errstr = null;
        $connection = fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr);
        if (!$connection) {
            // TODO Use a specific exception!
            throw new Exception('Connection failed!' . ' ' . $errno . ' ' . $errstr);
        }
        return $connection;
    }

    protected function closeConnection(resource $handle)
    {
        return fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you are going about this the right way. If I've understood you correctly, you're effectively wanting to test PHP built in methods (fwrite, feof etc) against a mocked/fake resource object returned from `$resource->openConnection()`. You should consider instead to have a wrapper object around those methods, so that you can test `$resource->write('something')` instead of `fwrite($resource, 'something')`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! No, for sure, I'm not going not test native functions. And, yes, I've create the methods, that wrap the connection setting related PHP functions. But now I want to mock their result for testing of the `barIntrefaceMethod()`, that calls these wrapping functions. The problem is only, that I don't find any way to fake the [`resource`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). That frustrates mocking of the `openConnection()`.

Comment: I know you won't test the native functions, but you have to call them in your code and they are dependent on a real resource handle. The easiest and better designed way of doing this is to have an object wrapped around the native functions, and mock *that* instead. I shall post an answer to explain what I mean better in code.

Answer (score 6):

As per my comments, I think you would be better off refactoring your code a little to remove the dependency on native functions being actually called with an actual resource handle. All you care about for the test of the `FooClass::barInterfaceMethod` is that it returns a response. That class need not concern itself with whether the resource is opened, closed, written to, etc. So that is what should be mocked out.

Below I have rewritten what you have in your question to demonstrate, in some simplistic and non-production pseudo-code:

Your real class:

```
class FooClass
{
    public function barInterfaceMethod()
    {
        $resource = $this->getResource();
        $resource->open($this->host, $this->port);
        $resource->write('some data');

        $response = '';
        while (($line = $resource->getLine()) !== false) {
            $response .= $line;
        }

        $resource->close();

        return $response;
    }

    // This could be refactored to constructor injection
    // but for simplicity example we will leave at this
    public function getResource()
    {
        return new Resource;
    }
}
```

Your test of this class:

```
class FooClassTest
{
    public function testBarInterfaceMethod()
    {
        $resourceMock = $this->createMock(Resource::class);
        $resourceMock
            ->method('getLine')
            ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls('some data', false)); // break the loop   

        // Refactoring getResource to constructor injection
        // would also get rid of the need to use a mock for FooClass here.
        // We could then do: $fooClass = new FooClass($resourceMock);
        $fooClass = $this->createMock(FooClass::class);
        $fooClass
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getResource');
            ->willReturn($resourceMock);

        $this->assertNotEmpty($fooClass->barInterfaceMethod());
    }
}
```

For the actual `Resource` class, you don't need to then unit test those methods that are wrappers around native functions. Example:

```
class Resource
{
    // We don't need to unit test this, all it does is call a PHP function
    public function write($data)
    {
        fwrite($this->handle, $data);
    }
}
```

Lastly, the other alternative if you want to keep your code as-is is to setup test fixture resources that you actually connect to for test purposes. Something like

```
fsockopen($some_test_host, $port);
fopen($some_test_data_file);
// etc.
```

Where `$some_test_host` contains some data you can mess with for tests.

Comment: Why not `$this->assertSame("some data", $fooClass->barInterfaceMethod())`; is better i guess?

Answer (score 3):

Resource mocking requires some magic.

Most of I/O functions allows to use a [protocol wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php). This feature used by [vfsStream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/) to mock the file system. Unfortunately the network functions such as [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) *don't support it*.

But you can to override the function. I don't consider the [Runkit](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.runkit.php) and [APD](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.override-function.php), you can do it without PHP extensions.

You create a function with same name and custom implementation in the current namespace. This technique is described in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337635/1220930).

Also the [Go! AOP](https://github.com/goaop/framework) allows to [override](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/08/24/intercepting-execution-of-system-functions-in-php/) any PHP function in most cases. [Codeception/AspectMock](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock) uses this feature to [functions mocking](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock#override-even-standard-php-functions). The [Badoo SoftMocks](https://github.com/badoo/soft-mocks) also provides this functionality.

In the your example you can completely override `fsockopen()` by any method and use vfsStream to call the `fgets()`, `fclose()` and other I/O functions.
If you don't want to test the `openConnection()` method you can mock it to setup the vfsStream and return the simple file resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following. It won't be a mock but at least the function which requires a resource won't crash and your unit test will go through.

```
$resource = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
```