# PHPUnit Cannot stub or mock class or interface "resource" which does not exist

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to mock or stub a "resource" type. This code confirms that PHPUnit can use the "resource" type, but it throws an error when I try to mock it. Error: Cannot stub or mock class or interface "resource" which does not exist.

What am I missing?

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class TestDataAccess extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetDataVersion() : void
    {
        $file_pointer = fopen("../data/users.txt", "r");
        self::assertTrue(is_resource($file_pointer)); //verifies PHPUnit can use "resource" type
        
        // all of these die on error:
        // Cannot stub or mock class or interface "resource" which does not exist
        //$resourceMock = $this->createStub(gettype($file_pointer));
        $resourceMock = $this->createStub(resource::class);
        //$resourceMock = $this->createMock(resource::class);

        /* what I'm actually trying to test
        $data_format = "1.0";
        $resourceMock
            ->method('getLine')
            ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls("#version:".$data_format, false));
        $result = my_method_under_test($resourceMock);
        self::assertSame($data_format, $result);
        */
        
        fclose($file_pointer);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `resource` is a special variable in PHP, not a class. You've been thrown off by the fact that `anything::class` will work and return the string "anything", so the framework will assume it's a class. So you'll need to refactor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300828/how-to-fake-a-resourse-for-a-unit-test-in-php

Comment: Thanks, @soulseekah, that makes sense.  For now I am going to test using real files.  There are edge cases such as "did you rewind before reading the file?" that can't be tested with mocking a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments: "resource" is not actually a class. File pointers can be wrapped to enable some testing, or possibly can be mocked with another plugin.